# iCloud: Key-value storage issues

Tags: ios, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

Does anybody have a success story about key-value storage on iCloud? I spent hours to figure out why doesn't my app sync between devices using NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore.

There are points I went through atm:

-I'm storing an NSData object archived from array of custom objects

-the notification NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification never posted (this is main problem)

-the notification NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification posted correctly when I change account or logout from iCloud

-the data I store to NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore with setData:forKey: is coming back to me when I send dataForKey: message but the data is never synced with other devices

-I've already tried to remove the app, remove iCloud account, reinstall the app, relogin to iCloud - nothing helps to sync data between devices

-my devices: iPod 4 touch on iOS6 and iPhone 4 on iOS6.1.3

-tons of articles and tutorials

-entitlements and provisions are fine (at least I don't get any errors)

Any ideas?

Comment: i have some issues will you help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I enabled Use Cellular Data, the syncronization started to work on iPhone

**DAMN YOU APPLE!**

*P.S. looks like an OS bug*